# Sick gecko who won’t eat

Tags: leopard-geckos

[image]
I adopted a leapard gecko yesterday because the people caring for it could not get it to eat. The gecko is very thin. And will not eat. The skin around her eyes has not shed and she can’t open them. She does not move around a lot, and I would like her to get better. I bought a appatite  stimulant that is supposed to help reptiles gain weight. Please help

Comment: Have a look at the answers on this post https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17095/gecko-wont-eat. Let us know if they don't work. Keep us posted. I hope the poor thing is ok.